# Android Studio java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed when picking date from date picker

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app for university for registering invoices. I have an `Activity` with a vendor class where I register them (code, name, phone number) and one `Activity` for registering invoices (code, series, date, explanations and vendor)

For inputting the date I used a `TextView` that when tapped, another dialog `Activity` opens with a `DatePicker`.

My problem is that when I press Submit, the app crashes and the following exception is triggered in the debug:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-11-9' could not be parsed at index 8
```

This is the code for the date class, save button and calendar dialog fragment:

```
private LocalDate date;

public void setDate(LocalDate d) {
    date = d;
}

public LocalDate getDate() {
    return date;
}

public TextView date;
private Invoice invoice;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_invoice);
    date = findViewById(R.id.idDate);

    Button btnSave = findViewById(R.id.btnSaveInvoice);
        
    data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calendarDialog calendar = new calendarDialog();
            calendar.show(getFragmentManager(),"calendarDialog");
        }
    });

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            invoice = new Invoice();
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(data.getText());
            invoice(date);
        }
    });
}
```

```
public class calendarDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,     @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(layout.calendar_my_dialog,container,false);
        CalendarView      calendarView=view.findViewById(id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int Year, int Month, int dayOfMonth) {
              int month = Month+1;
              String txtDate = Year+"-"+Month+"-"+dayOfMonth;
                ((activity_invoice)getActivity()).date.setText(txtDate);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive `String`s like `"2021-11-9"`, which are of the format `"uuuu-MM-d"` but when you try to parse them with `LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(data.getText());` you are implicitly using the standard ISO format, which has the pattern `"uuuu-MM-dd"` and is, therefore, expecting a `String` like `"2021-11-09"` (two digits for day of month). Your ones are missing a digit, at least when the day of month is less than 10.

You can pass a formatter that handles the single-digit format:

```java
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-d");
```

and then parse the `String` using that formatter:

```java
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(data.getText(), dtf);
```

Comment: @CatalinPetraru You're welcome, please consider accepting this answer and/or upvoting it (as soon as you have enough reputation) ;-)

Comment: `LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(data.getText());` should probably have a try catch around it then for this type of thing, right ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yes, it should or the method that calls it should have a `throws`…  But this answer does not contain a fully executable example, so I just skipped it for brevity.

Comment: it's fine, this was just as a note to OP more than anything :)

Comment: thank you a lot guys, I'm pretty new to programming